# ASP.NET loop through a list inside and another loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a list inside another list like so:

```
var collectionsList = db.Data.ToList().Select(m => new { m.collection, m.hidden }).Where(model => model.hidden == false).Distinct();

            foreach (var item in collectionsList)
            {
                ViewData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(item.collection, db.Data.ToList().Where(model => model.collection == item.collection)));
            }

            return View();
```

Now in my view I am trying to loop through ViewData and then loop through the lists inside the ViewData like so:

```
var collectionsList = db.Data.ToList().Select(m => new { m.collection, m.hidden }).Where(model => model.hidden == false).Distinct();

        foreach (var item in collectionsList)
        {
            ViewData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(item.collection, db.Data.ToList().Where(model => model.collection == item.collection)));
        }

        return View(); 


@foreach (var item in ViewData)
           {
               <h1 style="padding-bottom:50px;">item.Key</h1>
               <table class="table">
                <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #333;">
                    <th>
                        Design
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Size (sq ft.)
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align: right;">
                        Price
                    </th>
                </tr>
                @foreach(var x in item.Value as List<CP.Models.Pricing>)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.sqft) sq ft.
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                            $@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.basePrice)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
                </table>
           }
```

But I get this error on the second loop: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` Why am I getting this error? and how can I fix it?

Comment: which line, specifically - pretty much one of the simplest error messages in .net too; whatever line is throwing the error has a null object that you are trying to reference a property on.

Comment: this line....@foreach(var x in item.Value as List<CP.Models.Pricing>)

Comment: so either Value is null or item is null. you also don't need the `as` part

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I *really* recommend using a view model for this.

Comment: example @nurdyguy

Comment: @Darren I removed the as part and now I get this error `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: @user2551750 - you spelt "i want copy and paste code please" wrong.. :)

Comment: @user2551750  Here is a basic fiddle with a view model.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/MjANsj

Answer (score 0):

x is null ? Causing your @Html.Display's to error.

I'd suggest a simple trial-and-error elimination process, i.e. comment out the DisplayFor's and see if the error disappears. This will help narrow down the cause.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "ViewData" instead of "ViewData["KeyName"]". If you are using only ViewData it will consider all ViewData values along with required data. for example **WEBPAGE TITLE** will also go into foreach loop. That may be causing the issue.

I would suggest you to please specify "ViewData["KeyName"]" instead of ViewData. So that the loop will run only for specified ViewData key.

Example Code which is working all fine for me is as below:

**ViewData declaration and assignment**

```
ViewDataDictionary vd = new ViewDataDictionary();
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add("Data1User1");
lst.Add("Data2User1");
lst.Add("Data3User1");
lst.Add("Data4User1");
vd.Add("User1", lst);

lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add("Data1User2");
lst.Add("Data2User2");
vd.Add("User2", lst);

ViewData["vdt"] = vd;
```

**Razor Code to loop through a list inside and another loop**

```
@foreach (var vdt in ViewData["vdt"] as ViewDataDictionary)
{
    <h1 style="padding-bottom: 50px;"> @vdt.Key </h1>

    <table class="table">
        <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #333;">
            <th>Design
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var x in vdt.Value as List<string>)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @x
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Please follow above mentioned approach and correct you code.

Hope this will help you and please do let me know if you need any more information.